# How to sync data when joining to a photon rooms that created before?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to build a game like http://slither.io/, using **Photon Unity networking**. The problem is here that I don't know how to get data from a photon room that was created before. for example, we have a room that already has 10 players and a new player wants to join this room.

I already know that if two or more players are in a room I can use `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate()` to create some object to share data of that special object with players in the room.

One possible solution that comes to my mind is to create one GameObject for every player who is in the room with a `PhotonView` component and photon **will** update data of those objects. Is that OK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I got from the Photon forum :

> You can store data in room properties, use buffered RPC's, or even get
>   data from master on joining room.

hope it helps.